# Excluding a particular style

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have defined a style for all images:

```
img {
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}
```

I would like to style another set of images differently. I have created a class for them:

```
.radius {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

However, it does not seem to change the targeted images. As I understood it, a class selector has a higher priority than an element selector. Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Comment: **If you're going to bold all the text, why use bold at all?**

Answer (score 1):

Have al look at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity

```
A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:

- count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= a)
- count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in the selector (= b)
- count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the selector (= c)
- ignore the universal selector
```

For example you can increment your specificity by using tag + class

```
img.radius {
     border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[Here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) a good article from SM

Comment: Thanks Antonello. Strangely, it still didn't seem to work. I specified using two html selectors, which did the trick.

Comment: 'a img {border-radius: 10px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display:block; }'